# How to stop scrolling of page when user use the signature pad in xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, signaturepad

I am using xamarin.forms to develop the Android app. I need to use Signature Pad in my app. I have used the signature pad successfully. But the screen in which signature pad is placed has lot of controls. So screens scrolls vertically.

My problem is when user try to do signature at signature pad it starts to scroll vertiacally and user can't sign at signature pad. User can draw only av vertical line.

Please tell me how I can stop the vertical scrolling when user tries to do signature at signature pad.

Regards,
Anand dubey

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the trouble of trying to nest this view. The signature pad isn't really designed to be contained in other views. You really have to approach this from a design perspective and find a way to have this control occupy the whole screen, whether that's a modal or a dedicated page.

If you're really trying to nest the view, I once had some minor success in recursively finding the signature pad's parent views until I came across the scroll layout. I would then disable the scroll layout until touches ended, then re-enable scrolling on touch finished. However I would strongly recommend against doing this.

Comment: Hi @AllDayer, could you please update me how you got the touch event of signature pad? Or In which event you disable the parent scroll layout? I was trying with Focused and Unfocused event of signature pad but its never called? Please update in which event you disable the scroll layout?